# Memory leak issue in python Machine learning code

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory-leaks, fastapi

I am using python code to deploy the pre-trained machine learning model on fast API.I am containerizing my model by using docker. The API code is working fine but after every API hits it doesn't free the memory it uses. After every hit, the memory keeps on increasing. This is the code I am using,

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pickle

from transformers.pipelines import pipeline

class QAItem(BaseModel):
    context: str
    question:str

with open('model_pickle','rb') as file:
    nlp = pickle.load(file)

app=FastAPI()

@app.post('/api')
def qanda(data:QAItem):
    data=data.dict()
    item=nlp(question=data['question'],
             context=data['context'],
             handle_impossible_answer=True,
             max_answer_len=500)
    json_compatible_item_data=jsonable_encoder(item)
    return JSONResponse(json_compatible_item_data)


if __name__=='__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app,host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I see two options: 1 - there is some issue with `nlp(...)` function; 2 - there is a problem with Docker. I suggest to comment out the code that related to the ML model and check the memory leak. Otherwise, it might helpful to look into the Dockerfile.

Comment: can you give an update - have you solved this issue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My experience with transformer-based NLP models is that they are very demanding, and sometimes leaking memory.

For example I've had issues with Facebook's Bart large CNN model (for summarization) that is behaving pretty much the same way (memory keeps increasing).

A dirty workaround would be to limit the maximum amount of memory used by your Docker container so that, once the limit is reached, Docker restarts the container and frees all the memory. This is not 100% satisfactory but it works, and you won't break your host...